# Custom jQuery and CSS in theme header

Tags: jquery, css, header, themes

How to add this code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/cometchat/cometchatcss.php" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cometchat/cometchatjs.php" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

in custom jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
    //Your codes strat from here
});
```

Comment: Do you mean "How to create a <link> and a <script> tag from jQuery instead of as HTML"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**jQuery**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
$('head').append('<link type="text/css" href="/cometchat/cometchatcss.php" rel="stylesheet" charset="utf-8"><script type="text/javascript" src="/cometchat/cometchatjs.php" charset="utf-8"></script>');
});
```

Comment: thank you but its not work for me...i want set chat slide at bottom of site using comet chat plugins,,,, like this site please visit this site http://wishyou.comxa.com/    so where and how put above code in theme for effect as http://wishyou.comxa.com/